# SharePoint Farm containing two servers, how to configure one server to work in case the other went down

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, administration, installation, server-farm

I have SharePoint 2013 server. And the customer required to have two servers inside the same farm. So in case one server went down to have the other server working. So how I can configure such a scenario within SharePoint 2013 Farm.

Comment: Do you mean a one server install with failover or just the Web Front Ends having failover in case one Web Server goes down?

Comment: I mean Web Front Ends having failover in case one Web Server goes down

Comment: Go for a Hardware NLB.

Comment: We handle ours with a Load Balancer that just redirects to the other server in case one is not reachable

Comment: could you provide me with some material expaining this.?

Comment: and should the two servers be on the same Farm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way is to join the second server to farm and create NLB (software or hardware) using both of them.

Software NLB can be created e.g. using Windows Server Network Load balancing, hardware NLB - using some devices like Cisco GSS.

Those links may help:

[Windows Server 2008 NLB](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732855%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[Windows Server 2012 NLB](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831698.aspx)